# SQL Server : syntax issue with overlapping dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having issues with a select that I can't seem to wrap my head around. I have web front end that has a business rule where date ranges cannot overlap and I need to identify them and remove those records before I import so that our BU and handle them manually. I have 3 columns `Dealer_Number`, `Date_From` and `Date_To`.

For example you see that I have 2 data ranges of: 11/01/2017 to 11/30/2017 and 11/01/2017 to NULL which technically they overlap.

I also have instances where I have the below date ranges which also overlap that I need to identify and remove:

```
05/02/2017 to 07/16/2017
03/05/2017 to 08/03/2017
```

[image: Example]

I started with the below and I've tried using between etc but can't get it to return what I'm expecting:

```
SELECT 
    dealer_number, Date_From, Date_To 
FROM
    [MyTable] 
WHERE 
    dealer_number = 'HD0421' 
GROUP BY 
    dealer_number, Date_To, Date_From  
HAVING 
    COUNT (Date_From) > 1 
ORDER BY
    dealer_number ASC
```

DDL

```
 CREATE TABLE #tmp 
 (
     Dealer_Number [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
     Date_From DATETIME NULL,
     Date_To DATETIME NULL
 )

 INSERT INTO #tmp 
 VALUES ('HD0421',  '11/01/2017', '11/30/2017'),
        ('HD0421',  '11/01/2017', '11/30/2017'),
        ('HD0421',  '11/01/2017', '11/30/2017'),
        ('HD0421',  '11/01/2017', '11/30/2017'),
        ('HD0421',  '11/01/2017', NULL),
        ('HD0421',  '11/01/2017', NULL),
        ('HD0421',  '11/01/2017', NULL),
        ('HD0421',  '11/01/2017', NULL),
        ('HD0421',  '12/01/2017', '01/25/2018'),
        ('DRE456',  '05/12/2017', '11/12/2017') , 
        ('DRE456',  '11/13/2017', '12/12/2017'),
        ('DRE456',  '01/12/2017', '06/12/2017'),
        ('DRE456',  '05/12/2017', '11/12/2017');
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks Yogesh this looks to be going in the right direction but still not quite what I'm looking for. Let me try to explain.

Comment: . . (1) All the data ranges overlap, as far as I can tell.  (2) What result do you want?

Comment: Thanks Yogesh this looks to be going in the right direction but still not quite what I'm looking for. Let me try to explain. 'HD0421', '11/01/2017','11/30/2017' and 'HD0421', '11/01/2017','11/30/2017' do not overlap. 'HD0421', '11/01/2017','11/30/2017' and 'HD0421', '11/01/2017',NULL do overlap. ('DRE456',  '05/12/2017', '11/12/2017') and ('DRE456',  '01/12/2017', '06/12/2017') overlap. Those are the ones that I need to identify.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` function to generate the `Seq` and fileter them and remove to avoid overlapping of dates

```
select * 
from (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by Dealer_Number, Date_From, Date_To order by Date_From) Seq
      from tmp
     ) t
where seq > 1;
```

Comment: Hi Yogesh. Thanks for the response. Actually I'm not wanting to delete them, I only want it identity them. Thanks

Comment: @PeteMiller... Then remove `delete` statement and write `SELECT` statement.